# Change form POST data before submit with jQuery not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm currently trying to change the value of a hidden input in my form during the form submit. So first I've my hidden input:

```
<input autocomplete="off" class="um-form-field valid not-required " type="text" name="webauthn_result-320" id="webauthn_result-320" value="" placeholder="" data-validate="" data-key="webauthn_result">
```

Now I'm using this function to do some things before the form submit. To get the results to the backend, I want to modify the form so that I can access them with `$_POST` in PHP:

```
jQuery(document).on('submit', '#login-form', function () {
    var someVarialbel = 20;
    jQuery('input[data-key=webauthn_result]').val(['success', someVarialbel]);
});
```

Sadly, it don't works. I've checked the backend and the value is empty. Any idea whats wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this.

> You will need to use `preventDefault` to make any changes.

```
$("#form_id").on("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();//stop submit event
    var self = $(this);//this form
    $("#change_value").val("deneme");//change input
    $("#form_id").off("submit");//need form submit event off.
    self.unbind('submit');
    self.submit();//submit form
});
```

Comment: This creates a loop because with submit() the same function get's triggered again and again.

Comment: @Mr.Jo, I have added an unbind to prevent loop.

Comment: What about .one("submit", ...)?

Comment: It is unbinding before submitting form, on.("submit") will not get called after that. You can bind it again after self.submit(), like this..
self.bind('submit');

Comment: Thanks for your help, got it :) I've removed .off and .unbind and used the .one("submit") method. This is much simpler. But you helped me to get on the right way so thanks for this!

Comment: @Mr.Jo according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event, the 'submit' event is not sent to the form when form.submit() is called, so there should be no loop.

Answer (score 0):

From jQuery Documentation: [Here is the link](https://api.jquery.com/submit/)

> For example, consider the HTML:
>
> ```
> <form id="target" action="destination.html">
>   <input type="text" value="Hello there">
>   <input type="submit" value="Go">
> </form>
> <div id="other">
>   Trigger the handler
> </div>
> ```
>
> The event handler can be bound to the form:
>
> ```
> $( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {
>   alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
>   event.preventDefault();
> });
> ```
>
> **Now when the form is submitted, the message is alerted. This happens prior to the actual submission**, so we can cancel the submit action by calling .preventDefault() on the event object or by returning false from our handler. We can trigger the event manually when another element is clicked:

Answer (score 0):

You can set value in JSON format as below:

```
jQuery(document).on('submit', '#login-form', function () {
    var someVarialbel = 20;
    jQuery('input[data-key=webauthn_result]').val(JSON.stringify(['success', someVarialbel]));
});
```

Hope it help you!